# Issue with trashcan in panel

Tags: 11.04, gnome-panel, trash

I am running Natty and I have the trashcan applet in one of my panels in Gnome and when I drag items to the trash can they get put into the panel instead.  I can still put things in the trash can by right-clicking on them and moving them to trash.  And I can click the trash can to view the items in it and empty it, but it always shows as full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion I have would be to check for hidden files within the trash can by pressing Ctrl+H to show these hidden files.
As far as dragging items to the trash can, this is a good idea and you might want to propose it do someone who develops the Unity interface. You can find them on Launchpad here: https://launchpad.net/unity

Comment: I'm not using Unity, just Gnome.  I'm pretty sure you could drag items to the trash in 10.10.

Comment: +1 for checking hidden files!  Thanks for that!

Comment: It fixed part of the problem but since no one else has posted I'll accept it.